# Converting 2D array into [ [ x0 y0 ] [x1 y1] [x2 y2] ] form

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I am looking to convert the array:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]
```

into

```
[[1 10][2 20][3 30][4 40][5 50]]
```

Is there an easy way to do this? And what is the technical name for the second type of array?

NOT

```
[[1, 10][2, 20][3, 30][4, 40][5, 50]]
```

Comment: `[list(i) for i in zip(*l)]` or simply `list(zip(*l))` if list of tuples is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ans = []
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
...   ans.append([a,b])
... 
>>> ans
[[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30], [4, 40], [5, 50]]
```

Comment: I updated, the question, but that answer isn't quite what I am looking for. Pretty much, I am trying to convert my 2D array of X and Y values into the same format as in the sample code of the project I am working on. In the sample code, the lists are created like this:  `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)`

Comment: Print X_train and you will see what I mean.

Comment: What is `[1 10]`? `[1, 10]` is a list with two elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to get the result

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]
result = [list(x) for x in zip(*arr)]
```

Comment: The output I get has commas in it, I updated the question.

Comment: without comma u want a string as output

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ls =[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]

res = [list(x) for x in zip(*ls)]

new_list = []
for i in res:
    item = ''.join(str(i).split(','))
    new_list.append(item)
print(new_list) #['[1 10]', '[2 20]', '[3 30]', '[4 40]', '[5 50]']
```

after join new_list,it look like

```
print([''.join(new_list)]) #['[1 10][2 20][3 30][4 40][5 50]']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not MATLAB's like syntax in Python, you cannot define list or arrays like this.

```
A = [[1 2 3], [4 5 6]]
```

You must separate every value by comma.